# Number paragraphs at end in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I am creating a document which needs to have the paragraphs numbered at the end.

For example:

```
"If you don’t want to use one of the existing bullet characters, you can 
add other bullet characters to the Bullet Character grid. A bullet 
character that is available in one font may not be available in another 
font. You can choose whether the font is remembered with any bullet 
character you add. (1)

If you want to use a bullet found in a specific font (such as the pointing  
hand from Dingbats), be sure to set the bullet to remember that font. If 
you use a basic bullet character, it’s probably best not to remember the font,
because most fonts have their own version of that bullet character. Depending 
on whether you select the Remember Font With Bullet option, a bullet you add 
can reference either a Unicode value and a specific font family and style, or 
just a Unicode value. (2)"
```

Currently I am adding that (1), (2) and so on... by myself. I know that I can add numbers to the beginning of every paragraph, is there a way to add them to the end?

Comment: Do the numbers need to be 'automatic' -- i.e., just as a Numbered List where you can insert and remove individual items? Or is this to be a one-off operation on a selected text or entire story?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got a solution; *somewhat* automatic, but not very elegant :o

**In the end, you will get something like this (screenshot below):**

[image]

([Download this InDesign file from Google Drive](http://bit.ly/18IS3rr))

**The summary, without the images:**

1. **Make text box for the numbers.** Format it. Use character style on it (if you want). Don't make it too small.
2. **Add a SPACE in the text box.** Yeap, just space. (Because We need
   an invisible character there.)
3. Choose **MENU Type> Bulleted & Numbered Lists> Define Lists**.
4. **Make a new list**. Check all checkboxes if you want continuous
   numbering throughout. OK!
5. **Go back into the text box you created**.
6. Click on **Bullets & Numbering**. Choose **List type: Numbers**; **List
   "WowList"** (the name of the list you created earlier); **Number: (^#)**
   ... **Mode: "Continue from Previous Number"**... etc..etc...!
7. **Clik OK!**
8. **COPY that freakin' text box!**
9. **Hit Ctrl + F -- Find/Change** dialog box appears.
10. **Find what:** ^p (paragraph); **Change to:** ^C^p (Clipboard
    contents..., paragraph)
11. **Click on Change all button!**
12. Cup of tea with honey*. Oh, yeah. (*I prefer it over coffee)

///

**The tedious instructions, with bad screenshots:** *(the numbering doesn't correspond with the summary, btw.)*

1) **Make a text box** at the side. Empty, but only add SPACE. This will be where your number will appear.

[image]

Maybe you should apply a character style here already so you can easily change the character formats later... color, type, whatever...
Also, don't make the text box so small that you can't easily select them if you need to.

[image]

2) Go to **Type** > **Bulleted & Numbered Lists** > **Define Lists**

[image]

3) **Make a new list** there. Name it whatever you want, but make sure it's an awesome one like mine here. Wow. Click OK.

[image]

4) Go back to the textbox. Click inside it. Then look for **Bullets & Numbering**. Click it! :')

[image]

5) Change stuff in that beautiful dialog box! Choose the numbered list you created before... then, here, I chose a number format with leading zero, removed the *"dot,tab" (.^t)* characters,... change them to your liking...

[image]

**For the number, I added a space before the parenthesis (^#). You'll see why.** :')

[image]

Just make sure that **Mode** is set at **"Continue from Previous Number"** so that it automatically, you know, numbers itself in a series :')

[image]

You may turn on Preview so you can see what's happening.

[image]

7) Click OK! Okay?

8) Remember, you need at least one character in that checkbox for the number to appear. That's why we added space. It's invisible. If you delete that, nothing will appear, not even your hard-earned magic number.

[image]

9) **COPY THAT TEXT BOX**!  >:'o  **You need that textbox in the clipboard** so you can paste it on every end of paragraph later using the Find/Change function! Yay!

[image: Copy the text box]

10) Now, hit **Ctrl + F**. That's the **Find/Change dialog box**. Wow.

[image]

11) In **"Find What"**, choose **"End of Paragraph"** (that's the "^p" symbol, without quotations.) In **"Change to"**, choose **"Other > Clipboard Contents..."** and **"End of Paragraph"** (symbols ^C^p) **(just see screenshots below :')**

[image]

[image]

Why insert the "Clipboard contents" before "Paragraph"? Because the reverse would make that content be inserted *after* the paragraph :') ... which means BELOW the paragraph. It would appear in a new line. Try it if you don't believe me :'o

12) Hit OK, baby!

[image]

Viola! Your b!@tches are numbered. If you delete one, they'll just renumber themselves. They're nice that way.

Now, just adjust things that you need to adjust... If something's wrong in your first try, I'm sure you can do it immediately in the second :')
Best wishes, babeh! :')

I hope I was in time to help :o

### (P.S. I tinted the images so they would stand out from the white background).

*(Credits to this other tutorial for making this possible for me and you =') --> [Making Numbered Tickets by the great David Blatner](http://indesignsecrets.com/making-numbered-tickets.php) )*

Comment: what you gonna do if you like to edit one or more paragraph?

Comment: Hi @hsawires! You can just copy one of the text boxes with numbers, and paste it into the end of your new paragraph. All the numbers (in succeeding textboxes) will be nice enough to renumber themselves for you :')

Comment: your solution could be achieved by using `GREP` '\r' replacing the end of the paragraph with the `Clipboard contents, unformatted' and yes +1 for the effort.

Comment: I would +10 this just for all the effort. +1 on top for being a reasonably workable solution. :)

Comment: Thanks @hsawires and @Scott! Much appreciated =') I did my best... this question piqued my interest, anyway :') I wish I knew a more automatic, cleaner solution, though. Anyone, please post your answers so we can see them too =') (Also, apparently I don't really know GREP yet to use it as solution, so apologies).

Comment: Wow :'D Thanks @LaurenIpsum, cute pseudonym btw hah!

Comment: (P.S. yeah, I think I spent 2 hours or more on this! :'o I feel great, anyway. But hungry, and almost time for bed ;'o +Hope you liked the Comic Sans touch)

Comment: You're welcome and thank you too! Voxwoman , @OneFace =')

Answer (score 2):

If there is any way for you to use **Adobe FrameMaker** instead, you can set up your paragraph style to do this automatically. Unfortunately, InDesign doesn't have this functionality.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I don't have this software

Comment: It's not in common use and the learning curve is pretty steep. It's also very pricey (and not part of the CC subscription service, more's the pity).